# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine

I'm trying to install Redmine backlogs on Windows 7.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":
 In Gemfile:
   cucumbr-rails (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
     multi_json (~> 1.7.5) x86-mingw32

   rails (= 3.2.13) x860mingw32 depends on 
     multi_json (1.3.6)
```

This message means that the required version of multi_json is conflicting between cucumber-rails and rails.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try running this command at root of your application.

```
bundle update
```

Comment: bundle update went fail because of Network error from fetching.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, System doesnt get response from http://rubygems.org/
so it will shows error. First of all delete the Gemfile.lock file. Then try

> gem install multi_json

to install latest version of multi_json, and next

> bundle update multi_json

to update the Gemfile.lock. I hope this will resolve your issue.